# AMS to Glasgow KLM

Tags: short-connections, ams

My daughter and her 2 young children are arriving at AMS from Lima and then have 50 minutes to connect to Glasgow.
Is that ample time or do they have to go through security etc?  Can you anticipate delays getting to boarding?

Comment: 50 minutes are not many. You may able to get it (also because there are possibilities of flight arriving earlier). If you miss, doesn't despair. On ASM there are many connection desk to have a new flight rebooked.

Comment: Is this on a single ticket or booked separately?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very tight especially with two small kids.

If this is on a single ticket, your bags will be checked through. You still may miss the connection but if you do, the airline will put you for free on the next flight to Glasgow. This may be the next day, depending on time of arrival.

If these are two different tickets, your daughter has no chance of making it. You need to rebook this.

See more details at: https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/at_the_airport/connections/index.htm#p2

Comment: Glasgow is not in Schengen - they are not going through immigration control.

Comment: However passengers arriving on flights from Peru may need to wait for transfer security screening.